# Data Consistency within the same Transaction

Tags: oracle

Any one can help on the below issue.
Thanks in advance.

I am updating a Table ACC_STATUS for Id 100

Current Value of Status Column is 0.

```
UPDATE ACC_STATUS
SET STATUS = 1
WHERE ID = 100;
```

After Update I am calling a Procedure, `pro_do_other_things`, which is in another Schema.

There is a SELECT From Table ACC_STATUS in this Procedure - pro_do_other_things. The result is not showing the updated value always. In some cases it shows the New Updated Value and in some other cases Old Value.

Please not that both Update Statement and Call to Procedure are happening in the Same Transaction as below.

```
BEGIN

   UPDATE ACC_STATUS
   SET STATUS = 1
   WHERE ID = 100;

   OTHER_SCHEMA.pro_do_other_things;

 COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ROLLBACK;

END;
```

Could anyone please explain why it is happening so?

Comment: maybe you have another `ACC_STATUS` table in the schema `OTHER_SCHEMA`

Comment: Is the procedure `other_schema.pro_do_other_things` defined as an `autonomous_transaction`? Or any other sub-procedure it calls defined that way?

Comment: Can you post a complete replicable example where we can see the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

By default the procedures are defined with definer rights (same as `AUTHID DEFINER`, see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm).
It means they are executed with the privileges of the schema they are defined in.
If there is a table without schema referenced in such stored procedure, the table is resolved as table from the definer's schema.

In your case the `OTHER_SCHEMA.pro_do_other_things` makes select from `OTHER_SCHEMA.acc_status`, not from `acc_status` in your schema.

When you define the procedure as `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`, then a referenced table without schema will be resolved as a table from the invoker's schema.

In this case the `OTHER_SCHEMA.pro_do_other_things` would make select from `acc_status` in your schema.

Note: When you always want to reference the same table regardless the invoker, you have to use it explicitly with schema or you have to create and use a synonym.

Comment: btw. but you should consider your DB design, usually the tables are defined in one schema, for every table there is a public synonym, the CRUD procedures are in another schema. if you have the same table in more schemas, you should think about duplicating the stored procedures too